# How can`RETURN TABLE(columns)` be equivalent to using one or more `OUT` parameters, and marking the function as returning `SETOF` record?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL document says

> There  is  another  way  to  declare  a  SQL function  as  returning  a  set,  which  is  to  use  the  syntax  `RETURNS TABLE(columns)` . This is equivalent to using one or more  `OUT`  parameters plus marking the function
>   as returning  `SETOF` record  (or  `SETOF`  a single output parameter's type, as appropriate).

Could you explain how `RETURN TABLE(columns)` can be equivalent to:

- using one or more  `OUT`  parameters, and
- marking the function
  as returning  `SETOF` record  (or  `SETOF`  a single output parameter's type, as appropriate)

Thanks.

Comment: The functions behave the same, regardless of how you define them.

Comment: Thanks. Does "plus" mean "or" or "together with"?

Comment: It means "together with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are equivalent:

```
create type my_type as (id int, str text);

create or replace function function_returning_setof(n int)
returns setof my_type language sql as $$
    select i, i::text
    from generate_series(1, n) i;
$$;

create or replace function function_returning_table(n int)
returns table(id int, str text) language sql as $$
    select i, i::text
    from generate_series(1, n) i;
$$;

create or replace function function_with_out_params(in n int, out id int, out str text)
returns setof record language sql as $$
    select i, i::text
    from generate_series(1, n) i;
$$;
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f2f639c7081dd477e2cbc9917a679ecb)